# The delay between a file delete (using unlink) and all the disk space being freed

Tags: c++, linux, unlink

I am deleting a temp file by unlinking and closing the file handle and then checking for the available disk space.
If I check the disk space immediately after the close handle , no space is freed.

```
...
//creating a temp file
int tempfile = open (filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0666);
unlink (filename);

//writing to temp file and reading from it
...

//Now we need to free disk space to make room for additional file writing.
//We no longer need the temp data in the file so we delete it.
statvfs(localDir,&sbuf1);
close(tempfile);
statvfs(localDir,&sbuf2);
//sbuf1.f_bavail == sbuf2.f_bavail

//I'd like to know HERE how much disk space I have for additional files,
//but I cannot really know since disk space is not freed yet.
```

If I add a delay (sleep(10)) , I can see space is being freed.

```
...
statvfs(localDir,&sbuf1);
close(tempfile);
sleep(10);
statvfs(localDir,&sbuf2);
//sbuf1.f_bavail < sbuf2.f_bavail
```

I have failed to find info about this delay between the delete and all the disk space being freed.

Waiting an arbitrary number of seconds is wastefull and not safe (my delay might not be enough for some file sizes).

Is there a blocking function that waits until the disk space is effectively freed, or some mechanism that can do  a similar job ?

Thanks

Comment: File is deleted when all file descriptors to it are closed. Does your program start any child processes, that might hold open file descriptor to the file?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm seeing here. `unlink` takes a `const char* pathname` and `close` takes an `int fd`. How do you pass the same object to both of them?

Comment: @SKi , My program is a single process. 
It seems to me that the file is indeed deleted at the close(), however the resulting change in the available disk space is not immediate.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `fsync()` function or the `sync` program? BTW, the info about this behaviour is simply the Linux source code. Performing these operations in the background just works sufficiently for most programs and has less perceived latency.

Comment: Why do you need to know the exact instant the space is available again ? Knowing it will be in the (near) future is usually sufficient.

Comment: @Shloim , You are correct. I have simplified the code. It is actually : open , unlink and later close. I will re-edit my code snippets.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt , I tried using fsync instead of the sleep - it din't work : the free disk space does not change immediately.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker , I am using the amount of available disk space in the code that comes after this snippet.

Comment: I understand that, but why do you need it to immediately reflect the change ?

Comment: You can't possibly use `fsync()`, because it needs an open file which in turn makes it impossible to reclaim the storage. I just wanted to make sure that this is something similar to what you are looking for, which you implicitly confirmed. What could perhaps work is if you `ftruncate()` the file to zero length first and then `fsync()` that change, but that's guessing. Also, check out the source code for `sync` for further inspiration.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, yes, that's what I'm wondering, too. Maybe this is a so-called XY-problem, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: @Rbik, I still do not understand why do you open the file? And why do you unlink it while it's open. switch the order to close and then unlink and see if it solves it.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Ulrich Eckhardt Shloim, I have edited the code to show more of the big picture and explain why I need to do this. Please keep in mind that this is just a small part of a large software that I would like to keep as it is. 
Parts of this code (the open and unlink for example) is in infra libs which I don't even have control of.
I am mostly looking for a technical solution to knowing how much disk space I have immediately after deleting my file.

Comment: @Rbik did you consider using `tmpfile()`? https://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile

Comment: @Rbik : you still haven't explained why you need this. Are you constantly working on a (near) full file system (that's a bad idea btw) ? Are you working with huge files ? Some more context can also help us understand better. Is this software the only user of the file system ? Which file system ? What are these files for ? How often are they created/deleted ? How many are there ? How time critical is it ? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provided, I would guess that you have the file open somewhere. It will be deleted only when you close it. There is no need to open a file in order to unlink it. Just call `unlink` with the pathname of the closed file.

Edit: Opening a file creates a link to it. So when the file is open you have 2 links to it: 1 from the filesystem and 1 from your program (you can see the link in /proc//) When you unlink the file you release 1 link to it, but the second link still exists until the fd is closed or until the process terminates (also, if you fork from your process, the file will get an additional link in /proc//).

Comment: I would reword that a bit: As long as the file is still open, its storage space can not be reclaimed, even though you `unlink()` the file. Remember, a file is independent from the directory entry referencing it. There may be even several such entries all referencing the same file, or none, as after unlinking.

Comment: It's not just reclaiming. There is an additional hard link in /proc/<pid>/<fd> that prevents the actual deletion. I stand by my answer, but added a clarification.

Comment: @Shloim , I am afraid that this is not a case of handle opened somewhere else.
I have written a small test code that opens,writes,unlinks and closes . If I check for disk space in the next command after closing , the space is not yet freed.
If I add a 1 second delay it is freed.
The interesting thing is that this behavior is not consistent over different computers. It does not happen on my desktop linux machine , but does on a node in a cluster (infiniband).

Comment: Does it still happen if you unlink after you close? does it happen with the `tmpfile()` system call?